# php xpath replacement doesn't carry certain value

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Here is my code:

```
       $xpath_query = $xpath->query('//div[@class="paragraph-content"]//h2[1]');
       $i = 0;
       foreach($xpath_query as $header){ 
          if (!empty($header->nodeValue) && $i == 0){
            $replacement  = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
            $replacement  ->appendXML("<h1>$header->nodeValue</h1>");
            $header->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement  , $header);
          }  
          $i++;
       }
```

I'm grabbing the `<h2>` tag in the xpath and replacing it with `<h1>`

Where there is a value like this "Dialed in to hike & trail" in the `<h2>` tag and its being replaced to `<h1>` tag it doesn't show the text.

the "&" or &amp is causing the replacement to break, the `$header->nodeValue`

how can I escape `$header->nodeValue`, meaning if there are cases in the string where I have a `<br>` tag or &amp. When I have a `<br>` tag or have & in the text, it breaks the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to ensure that the entities are encoded when you create the HTML (I've used `htmlentities()`)...

```
$replacement  ->appendXML("<h1>".htmlentities($header->nodeValue)."</h1>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by using this :

```
$replacement  ->appendXML("<h1>".htmlspecialchars($header->nodeValue)."</h1>");
```